# Store Lua string.match output to array

Tags: arrays, string, lua, lua-patterns

Normally I use two variables to store the output of something like this:

```
a = {'alarm boy car dentist','alarm car dentist elephant','alarm dentist elephant fabulous','alarm elephant fabulous goat'}
k, v = string.match(a[1], 'alarm dentist (%w+) (%w+)' )
print(k, v)
elephant fabulous
```

but instead of using two variables I would like to store it in an array or table.

My final goal is to create a function where I input an array (which in this case is 'a') and a pattern (which is this case is 'alarm dentist (%w+) (%w+)') and that it returns the desired accompanying word/s if found or 'nil' otherwise. The catch is that the number of word that the pattern looks for is undefined. In this case is 2 but I want the user to be able to input any pattern, i.e. 'alarm dentist (%w+) (%w+) (%w+) (%w+)' or 'alarm dentist (%w+)'.

So this was my line of thought so far: (I'm using the command line tool in Ubuntu 12.04LTS to test it)

```
a = {'alarm boy car dentist','alarm car dentist elephant','alarm dentist elephant fabulous','alarm elephant fabulous goat'}
function parse_strings (array, pattern)
words = nil
for i=1, #array do
    c = string.match(array[i], pattern)
    if c ~= nil then
        words = c
        end
    end
    return words
end
print (parse_strings (a, 'alarm dentist (%w+) (%w+)'))
elephant
```

but only the first value is stored in "c" instead of c[1]='elephant' and c[2]='fabulous'.

Worst case I could search for how many words the pattern is searching for but I would still need to find a way to store the undefined size output from `string.match` in one array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the result into a table:

```
local t = {string.match(array[i], pattern)}
if #t ~= 0 then
    words = t
    end
end
```

The return value of `parse_string` is a table now:

```
local result =  (parse_strings (a, 'alarm dentist (%w+) (%w+)'))
for k, v in ipairs(result) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Comment: Why not use `{ string.match(whatever) }` instead of `table.pack(string.match(whatever))` ?

Comment: @NiccoloM. You are right, I was overthinking. I've modified it to use a table constructor. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to ask this here, but this is my first question, do I have to do something else in addition to accept your answer?

Comment: @user3325563 Now that you have over 15 reputation, you can also upvote the answers that help you if you want. You don't *have to* do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two captures in your pattern, you need two result variables for `match`. Try:

```
words = nil
for i=1, #array do
    c,d = string.match(array[i], pattern)
    if c ~= nil then
        words = {c,d}
        return words
    end
end
```

This gives...

```
> for k,v in ipairs(words) do print (k,v) end
1   elephant
2   fabulous
```

Comment: Thanks, Doug.
Yes, this is how I normally do it, but the issue here is the undefined number of words to search (it can be 1,2,3,...), but the solution above addresses this.